# Redirect Subdirectories to Corresponding PHP file via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have been unsuccessful in finding out how to redirect subdirectories to the corresponding php file in the root. Everything I find is root to subdirectories.

I have the following subdirectories (for now)

```
/about  
/downloads  
/faq  
/terms  
/new-ua
```

and want them to load the content from the corresponding PHP file in the root directory

```
/about.php  
/downloads.php
/faq,php
/terms.php
```

and so on, so if you goto http://example.com/about it will load http://example.com/about.php and not modify the address bar.

There is some current content in .htaccess to redirect .asp to .php (as it was moved from a IIS host)

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule (.*)\.asp$ /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Thank you for your time and assistance. If there is already a question that answers this, please feel free to direct me to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash Off

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To internally forward /about to /about.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)